# using a string of C in android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a C program as following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
   printf("hello");
}
```

now i want to use this string "hello" in my android application. I researched about it and i got to know this is possible by using NDK. 
The .C file has to be converted into .SO file and then this library has to be included in the project. but i didn't get a proper way to do that.
Please elaborate the steps from the beginning that:
1)Do i need to return this string using a function in C program or this printing will do fine?
2)And then how do i convert this .C file in .SO file?
3)Then how to include this in android project?
4)And how i retrieve this string inside the application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The NDK includes plenty of examples. I suggest that you start by going through them.

Answer (score 0):

The NDK/JNI allows you to write code using C/C++ and then link it into your Java application. To setup NDK/JNI development you have to install NDK and then integrate it for android development. Follow this link for NDK development.

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/